# Rails controller#update giving incorrect type for params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I want to update a model using controller#update. I want to do this via AJAX and without having a hidden form or any DOM elements to keep in sync with my JS data.

How can I submit data to a controller#update via jQuery ajax?

My JS:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PATCH",
  url: "/uploads/" + current_upload.id,
  data: { 
    "upload[user]": user.id,
    "upload[upload]": current_upload.id 
  }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

My Controller:

```
  def update
    @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])

    # update the model.
    if @upload.update(upload_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def upload_params
      # permit! allows all attributes.
      params.require(:upload).permit(:user)
    end
```

Error:

```
User(#70101060061080) expected, got String(#70101055761460)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `"upload[user]": user.id` to be `"upload[user_id]": user.id`.

Within Rails, it's trying to assign `user` (a user instance) to be the string you're passing in via `user.id`, and complaining about the type mismatch.

Comment: interesting, is Rails also making `upload` (upload instance) out of `upload[upload]`? Ahhh so in `params.require()` I'm not specifying string values that are okay to be passed, I'm specifying object types. Is that correct?

Comment: well yes, because your controller is calling `@upload.update(upload_params)` (so passing the params you submit, into the update method). No you're not specifying user types, you're specifying params keys.

Comment: So now the error is gone, but the "user_id" field in my "uploads" db is not being updated. Is there something else 'magical' going on with Rails transforming my "user_id" parameter?

Comment: did you also change the `upload_params` method to permit `user_id` instead of `user`?

Comment: ah there we go. So this is saying "I require a hash of the form `upload[]`, and I permit `upload["user_id"]`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your request parameters have the "upload" parameter set to be "13" rather than a hash.

Comment: Ah - I'm sending this request through AJAX. Is the proper hash format upload[id] (required), upload[attr1], upload[attr2]?